# increment counter in a column based on certain condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
col1     col2
 -        -
 -        -
 no       1
 -        -
 no       2
 no       3
```

I have 2 columns in a dataframe. Whenever 'no' is encountered in col1, need to increment the counter in col2 as shown above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Campare values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`, then use cumulative sum and replace non `no` values to `-` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
m = df['col1'].eq('no')
df['col2'] = m.cumsum().where(m, '-')
print (df)
  col1 col2
0    -    -
1    -    -
2   no    1
3    -    -
4   no    2
5   no    3
```